# Keep the first tab always visible

Tags: c#, windows, forms, tabcontrol

I'm making a windows form application with tabs, and in my first tab I have a overview of the active tabs. Now when I add a new tab, the tabs are going in a sort of scroll bar and when the scrollbar is 'full', my first tab becomes 'out of sight'.
[image]
[image]

Is there an option to keep the first tab always visible? I've searched around the internet and couldn't find someone with the problem nor solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see any property for it yet but you have two way:

**1)** Create a custom control yourself (long way)

**2)** Use Multiline property of tabControl and set it to TRUE (Short way)

```
// Allows more than one row of tabs. 
   this.tabControl1.Multiline = true;
```

Result:................................ 
[image]

When you set Multiline to TRUE, it keep all tabs always visible (include first Tab) ;)

Also you can set **Appearance** property to **Bottom** or **FlatButtons** to prevent tabs moving after click on them in different lines.

```
this.tabControl1.Appearance= TabAppearance.FlatButtons;
```

Comment: This could be a solution, but why do the tabs order 'weird' when I click on a tab?

Comment: @user3122867, yes this is an another feature of TabControl, when you click on a Tab its row will be go UP (will be First Row) but you can use another value for Appearance property to fix it ;)

Answer (score 0):

No there is not.  You would need to design your own control to do this if that is what you want.